# GCD function doesn't work all the time

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to find the greatest common divisor of 2 numbers.

Let's say 1920 and 1080.

If I put this : `=GCD(1920;1080)` I get 120 which is good.

If I put 1920 in A1, 1080 in A2 and put this `=GCD(A1;A2)` in A3, then it also works.

But, in my case, I have this

A1 : `=LEFT(C1;4)` -> 1080

A2 : `=RIGHT(C1;4)` -> 1920

A3 : `=GCD(A1;A2)` -> 0

And I could not understand why the result in A3 was 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know how to answer my own question so I answer it there :

The problem was, =LEFT() give me something that is not recognized as a number.

So, to make it work I have to add (VALUE) before RIGHT and LEFT.

Here is the solution :

A1 : `=VALUE(LEFT(C1;4))` -> 1080

A2 : `=VALUE(RIGHT(C1;4))` -> 1920

A3 : `=GCD(A1;A2)` -> 120

And voilà !

Comment: Isn't the GCD of your numbers 120?

Comment: Yeap you're totally right ! it's corrected :)

Comment: This note is probably a bit late. In programming, we distinguish between various data types. The "format" in Excel serves a similar purpose. The result of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` has textual string type, whereas `GCD` expect numbers (integers to be specific).

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C1,4))
=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(C1,4))
```

[image]